# How do I show $P(\mathbb Q) = \mathscr B(\mathbb R) \cap \mathbb Q$

Tags: measure-theory

My first question is to confirm that $\sigma$-algebra generated by the set $\{ (a,b] \cap \mathbb Q \mid -\infty \leq a \lt b \leq \infty \}=\mathscr B(\mathbb R) \cap \mathbb Q$

where $\mathscr B$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Than how do I show $P(\mathbb Q) = \mathscr B(\mathbb R) \cap \mathbb Q$,

I think it is pretty clear that $\mathscr B(\mathbb R) \cap \mathbb Q \subset P(\mathbb Q)$ as $\mathbb Q \subset P(\mathbb Q)$. How about the other direction?

Comment: Note that you are abusing notation; in $\mathscr B(\mathbb R) \cap \mathbb Q$ you are intersecting a set of sets with a set of numbers; it's not true that $\mathbb Q \subset P(\mathbb Q)$ but $\mathbb Q \in P(\mathbb Q)$. You probably just wanted to say $\mathscr B(\mathbb R) \supset P(Q)$, i.e. every set of rationals is Borel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

Given $S \subset \Bbb Q$, what happens if you take the union of singletons $\{x\}$ for all $x\in S$?

Each singleton is closed, and $\mathscr B(\mathbb R)$, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, has all open and closed sets.

---

The comment is getting a bit long:

Only finite unions of closed sets are guaranteed to be closed, so you can't conclude $S$ is closed and it's not necessarily: take a sequence of rationals converging to an irrational, for example. It has a limit point, but it does not belong to the set of elements of the sequence.

But you can however conclude it's a Borel set, because $\sigma$-algebras are stable by countable unions, and $S$ must be countable since it's a subset of $\Bbb Q$.

I use $S$ because I need to prove that for all $S\subset \Bbb Q$, $S$ is also in $\mathscr B(\mathbb R)$, thus $P(\Bbb Q) \subset \mathscr B(\mathbb R)$.

---

By the way, using the same argument, you can prove that any *countable* subset of $\Bbb R$ is in $\mathscr B(\mathbb R)$.

However, there are (uncountable) subsets of $\Bbb R$ which are not Borel sets, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set#Non-Borel_sets) or [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32720/non-borel-sets-without-axiom-of-choice) on MathOverflow. There are probably also questions about this here on MSE.

Comment: So, let $A = $ union of singletons $\{ x \}$ in $S$, it is closed, hence is a subset of $\mathscr B$. Therefore $P(\mathbb Q) \subset \mathscr B \cap \mathbb Q$. Am I right? Also, why you let $x \in S \subset \mathbb Q$ not $x \in \mathbb Q$?

Comment: I see, thanks. Much clear now.